# Как реализовать PageControl на андроид?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, objective-c

Всем доброго времени суток!
Встал вопрос: необходимо реализовать элемент повторяющий элемент `PageControl`, который входит в состав `iOS` приложений на андроид! Как пока до меня не доходит. Конечно можно ручками прописать радиобаттоны и жесты пролистывания и вставить анимацию типа `slide_in` и `slide_out`. Но может все таки есть более простой выход из данной ситуации?
Ниже картинка того как это должно выглядеть!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации указанной вами задачи можно использовать ActionBar.Tab, для примера посмотрите на само устройство `Android` с несколькими рабочими столами и вы наглядно увидите как этот механизм реализуется в `Android`.

[Документация по Tab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html)

[Сравнение элементов `IOS` и `Android`](http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-and-android/)

- По сути вы можете практически любой элемент `Android` стилизовать под `IOS` и `Tab` не исключение

**Еще** взято от сюда [How to create an Page Control in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963629/how-to-create-an-page-control-in-android)

Вы можете сделать что то типа этого

```
int currentScreen = 1;

final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            new MyGestureDetector());

findViewById(R.id.homescreen).setOnTouchListener(
            new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                            ...detect scroll and change var...
```

Почитайте тут: [Android - HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView Touch Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling)

И тут: [Android horizontal scollview behave like iPhone (paging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595063/android-horizontal-scollview-behave-like-iphone-paging)

**дополнение**
Есть [официальный пейджинг от андроид](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)
[Ну и сравнение библиотек](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Есть еще [realviewswitcher](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.ru/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html)

Есть еще [horizontal pager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager)

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Буду пробовать. Но если честно я эту информацию по отдельности до этого нагуглил.)

Comment: Ну, теперь все собрано в кучу. Надеюсь это Вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

[ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)